# Capture elements on page load, remove them, then be able to use initial contents

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two DIV elements appearing on my page that I wish to capture on page load and be able to use the contents of until the page is refreshed (in their initial state).

One of the DIV elements is inside the other. Once the matched elements have been found on the initial page load, I wish to remove them, but it is important their contents is retained for later use by the script.

```
<div class="first-element">
    <!--- content --->

    <div class="second-element">
        <!--- content --->
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
    init: function(){

        // Capture first div but without second child div
        page.items.first = $('.div.first-element').remove('.second-element');

        // Capture second div
        page.items.second = $('.div.second-element');

        // Remove parent div from page
        $('body').remove('.div.first-element');


        // Be able to use initial page load found contents:
        
        // first = <div class="first-element"><!--- content ---></div>
        // second = <div class="second-element"><!--- content ---></div>

    },
});
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the `html` function : https://api.jquery.com/html/.

Comment: Retrieve the `.second-element` first. You've already removed it from the DOM before you try and read it

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery .detach() : https://api.jquery.com/detach/

```
var firstEl,secondEl;

secondEl = $(".second-element").detach();
firstEl = $(".first-element").detach();
```

Then you can reuse them with :

```
firstEl.appendTo( "body" );
secondEl.appendTo( "body" );
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make a var equal to the exact detached content? Also the outer element (parent) seems to be removed, leaving only what was inside..?

Comment: I've tried with $(firstEl)[0] == $(yourOtherJqueryElement)[0] it works.
And if your selectors are ok it should only detach what you need not the parent.
Maybe you can post more code to see what the problem is